# Why is copy constructor called twice? C++

Tags: c++, oop, copy, overloading, copy-constructor

So, I'm creating a class BigInteger for better understanding of how objects in class are constructed. So consider this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <exception>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct BigInteger
{
    const int base = 1000 * 1000 * 1000; //9 digits.
    bool negative = false;
    vector<unsigned long long> arr;

    BigInteger()
    {
#ifdef _DEBUG
        cout << "default constructor called" << endl;
#endif // DEBUG
    }

    BigInteger(const string& s)
    {
#ifdef _DEBUG
        cout << "string constructor called" << endl;
#endif // DEBUG
        /* crutch but seem to work
    left - left bound for reading the string to exclude the minus sign.
*/
        char left = 0;

        if (s[0] == '-')
        {
            this->negative = true;
            ++left;
        }
        for (int i = s.size() - 9; i >= left; i -= 9)
        {
#ifdef _DEBUG
            if (!(s[i] >= '0' && s[i] <= '9'))
            {
                throw std::invalid_argument("Error: expected a valid number");
            }
#endif // DEBUG
            this->arr.push_back(stoll(s.substr(i, 9)));

        }
        if ((s.size() - left) % 9 != 0)
        {
            this->arr.push_back(stoll(s.substr(left, (s.size() - left) % 9)));
        }
    }

    friend istream& operator>>(istream& in, BigInteger& obj)
    {
#ifdef _DEBUG
        cout << "istream& operator>> called: ";
#endif // DEBUG
        string s;
        in >> s;
        
        obj = BigInteger(s);

        return in;
    }

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const BigInteger& obj)
    {
        
        if (obj.negative)
            out << '-';
        out << obj.arr[obj.arr.size() - 1];
        string substr;
        for (int i = obj.arr.size() - 2; i >= 0; --i)
        {
            substr = to_string(obj.arr[i]);
            for (size_t i = 0; i < 9 - substr.size(); i++)
            {
                out << '0';
            }
            out << substr;
        }
        return out;
    }

    BigInteger(const BigInteger& obj) //copy constructor
    {
#ifdef _DEBUG
        cout << "copy constructor called" << endl;
#endif // DEBUG
        this->arr = obj.arr; 
    }

    BigInteger(BigInteger&& obj)  //move constructor
    {
#ifdef _DEBUG
        cout << "move constructor called" << endl;
#endif // DEBUG
        swap(obj);
    }

    ~BigInteger() //destructor
    {
#ifdef _DEBUG
        cout << "destructor called" << endl;
#endif // DEBUG
        arr.clear(); //probably because of RAII, I guess I don't have to write this
    }

    void swap(BigInteger& other)
    {
        std::swap(this->arr, other.arr);
        std::swap(this->negative, other.negative);
    }

    BigInteger& operator=(const BigInteger& rhs)
    {
#ifdef _DEBUG
        cout << "copy assignment called" << endl;
#endif // DEBUG=
        this->arr = rhs.arr;
        return *this;
    }

    BigInteger& operator=(BigInteger&& rhs) noexcept 
    {
#ifdef _DEBUG
        cout << "move assignment called" << endl;
#endif // DEBUG
        swap(rhs);
        return *this;
    }

    BigInteger& operator+=(const BigInteger& rhs)
    {
#ifdef _DEBUG
        cout << "operator+= called" << endl;
#endif // DEBUG
        size_t SIZE = max(this->arr.size(), rhs.arr.size()) + 1;
        this->arr.resize(SIZE);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        {
            if (i < rhs.arr.size())
            {
                this->arr[i] += rhs.arr[i];
            }
            if (this->arr[i] >= base)
            {
                this->arr[i] %= base;
                ++this->arr[i + 1];
            }
        }
        if (this->arr.back() == 0)
            this->arr.pop_back();
        return *this;
    }

    BigInteger operator+(BigInteger rhs)
    {
        return rhs += *this;
    }
};

int main()
{
    BigInteger a, b;
    cin >> a >> b;
    cout << a + b << endl;
}
```

So I'm trying to enter any numbers (for example 43 and 12). So I want to understand what happening  when I try to call `a + b` thing. So what do I expect:

1. Create copy of right-hand side object.
2. Do `operator+=` to this copy.
3. Return copy

So I expect only 1 copy. But somehow copy constructor is called twice! Here's the output:

```
default constructor called
default constructor called
istream& operator>> called: 43
string constructor called
move assignment called
destructor called
istream& operator>> called: 12
string constructor called
move assignment called
destructor called
//here the moment where a + b start to executing.
copy constructor called
operator+= called
copy constructor called
destructor called
55
destructor called
destructor called
destructor called
```

Why was it called twice? `Operator<<` doesn't call any copy constructor, I double-checked.

Comment: *"1. Create copy 3. Return copy"* *"So I expect only 1 copy."* I would expect 2 from your analyse.

Comment: So when I'm going out of the scope, the first copy is going to be destructed? And I need another copy?

Comment: Changing `return rhs += *this;` to `rhs += *this; return rhs;` would transform a copy into a move.

Comment: I think that rogue copy constructor and rogue third destructor is the temporary that was created from `a + b`. I'm not sure, so not making this an answer.

Comment: @Jarod42 Wow, that is unexpected to me. At first sight I thought they are semantically the same, but indeed I got move constructor instead of copy. And I don't understand why

Comment: NRVO doesn't apply to parameter, only to local variable.

Comment: [Copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) and [Automatic_move_from_local_variables_and_parameters](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/return#Automatic_move_from_local_variables_and_parameters) might interest you.

Comment: @Jarod42 I'm a little confused, but as I understood there's no NRVO optimization, not in your example not in mine?

Comment: `BigInteger operator+(const BigInteger& rhs) { BigInteger res{tmp}; res += *this; return res; }` might trigger NRVO (`res` is a local variable). `return rhs;` (from previous comment) could not trigger NRVO, the move is because `rhs` is a parameter.

Comment: @Jarod42 I see now! Thanks. But now I have a question. Which option will be more preferable in this case? In case of NRVO we create only one copy and construct it directly to the right spot. Meanwhile "Automatic move from local variables and parameters" tries to create an rvalue, then do something with it and then making a copy by stealing resources from this rvalue with move constructor.

Comment: It depends of cost of move/copy and simplicity. unique overload `BigInteger operator + (const BigInteger&, const BigInteger&)` is simpler (and generally sufficient) than adding additional overload to handling temporary at all possible places.

Comment: Use a power-of-2 base. Your future self will thank you. (Hint: How are you going to implement bit shifts with a 10⁹ base?)

Comment: Your `operator +` first obtains its argument by value (which is at least one copy) and then returns it by value (which is at least one copy). Pass the right-hand argument of `operator +` by a `const` reference. (You may also want to have a `&&` version that would scavenge and reuse a r-value argument’s internals.)